# Concierge is not loading properly

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, sabre

**Concierge installation** has **errors** and will not install.

I'm running cmd prompt as admin and I have also cleared cache. npm cache clean -f

Should I uninstall or delete a directory before trying to install again?
Is there a new version to install?
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thank you.

CMD is below

D:\SDK\red-app-sdk-3.0-windows\red-app-sdk-3.0-19.10\webmodules\tools\offline-bundle>npm install -g sabre-concierge-4.8.10.tgz
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.3 (node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules\sane\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for object-path@0.11.5: wanted: {"node":">= 10.12.0"} (current: {"node":"8.17.0","npm":"6.13.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: object-path@0.11.5
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for matcher@3.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.17.0","npm":"6.13.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: matcher@3.0.0
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for escape-string-regexp@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.17.0","npm":"6.13.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: escape-string-regexp@4.0.0
npm WARN airbnb-prop-types@2.13.2 requires a peer of react@^0.14 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-alpha but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.9.1 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN enzyme-adapter-react-16@1.9.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN enzyme-adapter-utils@1.12.0 requires a peer of react@0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN jest-environment-enzyme@7.0.2 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || >=16.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@16.7.0 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules@jest.transform.DELETE\node_modules@cnakazawa
npm ERR! dest C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules@jest\transform\node_modules@cnakazawa
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules@jest.transform.DELETE\node_modules@cnakazawa' -> 'C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules@jest\transform\node_modules@cnakazawa'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules@jest.transform.DELETE\node_modules@cnakazawa' -> 'C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules@jest\transform\node_modules@cnakazawa'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules@jest.transform.DELETE\node_modules@cnakazawa' -> 'C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules@jest\transform\node_modules@cnakazawa'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!      path: 'C:\xxxx\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules\@jest\.transform.DELETE\node_modules\@cnakazawa',
npm ERR!      dest: 'C:\xxxx\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules\@jest\transform\node_modules\@cnakazawa' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xxxx\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules\@jest\.transform.DELETE\node_modules\@cnakazawa' -> 'C:\xxxx\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules\@jest\transform\node_modules\@cnakazawa'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\xxxx\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules\@jest\.transform.DELETE\node_modules\@cnakazawa',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\xxxx\xxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sabre-concierge\node_modules\@jest\transform\node_modules\@cnakazawa',
npm ERR!   parent: 'sabre-concierge' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\xxxx\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-11-11T19_08_35_183Z-debug.log

D:\SDK\red-app-sdk-3.0-windows\red-app-sdk-3.0-19.10\webmodules\tools\offline-bundle>

Comment: I had this same issue a while back and required the help desk to do an RDP session to resolve it for me. I suggest calling Sabre. That concierge tool is wonky at best.

Comment: Thank you. I reloaded the most up to date versions on a new computer with admin access. So far everything is working fine.